# How to pass public value from parent class to child class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I just learn deeper about OOP in PHP, but not an expert yet. I'm still a beginner. I have a problem. I want to pass the public value from parent class to child class. But I cant get it. I tried to find the answer in google and stackoverflow, and I have tried to follow the instruction, but it didnt work.

My code is like below:

```
class A
{
    public $arrayperk;
    public $nilai;
    
    function __construct()
        {
            $this->nilai='This is bad';
        }
    function testParent()
        {
            return $this->arrayperk;
        }
    function testA()
        {
            return number_format(1000); 
        }
}

class B extends A
{
    function  coba()
        {
            return $this->testParent();
        }
    function  coba2()
        {
            return $this->testA();
        }
    function coba3()
        {
            return $this->nilai;
        }
}
```

The problem is that I want to pass **the value of $arrayperk** to the function inside **class B**. But it did not work at all.

My code is like below:

```
$arrayperk=Array( 1 => 'array1', 2 => 'array2');
$class_a=new A();
$class_a->arrayperk=$arrayperk;
$class_b=new B();

print_r($class_a->testParent()); //return array as needed.
print_r($class_b->coba()); //return nothing although it calls the parent class, and the parent work correctly if it is called like above. This is what I want to get and the problem I face.
echo $class_b->coba2(); //return 1,000 and it access the parent function
echo $class_b->coba3(); //return This is bad as written at parent class.
```

As you can see, the problem is at

```
$class_b->coba()
```

It gives nothing even I have call it correctly to the parent class, but the other test works fine when accessing the parent class function.

I am even unable to pass **$this->arrayperk** inside class B. It returns nothing. What am I missing? I cant get both **$this->arrayperk** and a function inside parent class.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The only way you could have your `$class_b` instance return the value you set for `$arrayperk` on your `$class_a` instance would be for you to change `$arrayperk` in class A to be static. You would also have to change the way it is set and accessed to match.

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating 2 different classes, `$class_a` and `$class_b`. Your're only setting the `$arrayperk` for `$clas_a`

```
$class_a=new A();
$class_a->arrayperk=$arrayperk;
$class_b=new B();
```

here when $class_b is instantiated, you don't give it any properties.
A simple fix would be to just assign the property:

```
$class_b->arrayperk = $arrayperk;
```

Even though you're inheriting the parent method, the actual property `$arrayperk`, in your case, is empty so you need to set it for each instance individually.

Inheritance means you inherit the methods of the parent class, but each instance behaves as a separate unit.

If you do

```
$class_c = new B();
var_dump($class_c->arrayperk);
```

This value would also end up being NULL

Also helps if you var_dump your values, instead of printing, since in this case you would see the value of arrayperk is NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I have set in class_b to call `function testParent()` inside class A. `$class_a->testParent()` returns correctly, and $class_b as the child call `$this->testParent()`, and it doesnt work. If I change the public value in Class A with this: `public $arrayperk=Array(1,2,3);`, it return **array 1,2,3** for class_b, and **Array( 1 => 'array1', 2 => 'array2')** for class_a. I have followed your suggestion to put `public $arrayperk;` inside class B and set `$class_b->arrayperk=$arrayperk;`, and yes it works.

Comment: Is that means that public value in parent class cannot be passed to child class although it is set inside the function in parent class?

Comment: This is the difference between class and instance. A class is like a blueprint of a functionality. When you say `class B extends A` you're telling B to extend the same methods (functions) and properties (variables) as class A, but when you actually call `$class_b=new B();`, the value of arrayperk for that instance is not set to anything, hence why you get NULL (or nothing in your case, since you're printing with `echo`). You would also get NULL if you call `$some_other_class = new A(); var_dump($some_other_class->coba())`

Comment: If you want the value of `arrayperk` to be accessible without explicitly setting it (what you do in `$class_a->arrayperk=$arrayperk;`), you can do something like `$this->arrayperk = ['some', 'values'];` in the `__construct` method of A, or B.  Alternatively, you can also give it a value in the class definition itself like `public $arrayperk = ['some', 'values'];`

Comment: I'd recommend watching some lectures on OOP in PHP to help you understand the principles of inheritance and what the difference between a class and an instance is.  Good luck!